# warnings found and -Werror specified [deprecation] LocationProvider in android.location has been deprecated

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, geocoder

I facing the error: warnings found and -Werror specified

```
/Users/sdaemoninfotech/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-6.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationManagerClient.java:10: warning: [deprecation] LocationProvider in android.location has been deprecated
import android.location.LocationProvider;
                       ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
/Users/sdaemoninfotech/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-6.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29: warning: [deprecation] isFromMockProvider() in Location has been deprecated
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isFromMockProvider());
                                        ^
1 error
2 warnings
warnings found and -Werror specified
```

I tried to downgrade flutter too. still facing the error

[image]

Comment: What about ugrading the geolocator library ? You're on 6.2.1 while now live is 7.7.1

Comment: Thanks... I added the latest version and solve all other dependency version conflicts and its work. followed below link for it.

https://iiro.dev/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/

Answer (score 4):

I have the following dependencies:

```
permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
geolocator: ^7.6.0
geocoding: ^2.0.0
```

and fix this by updating like this:

```
permission_handler: ^8.2.5
geolocator: ^7.7.0
geocoding: ^2.0.1
```

Also have in build.gradle `compileSdkVersion 31`

and

in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Simplest Solution is upgrading the flutter pub. It will solve this issue.

Comment: Hello Anees, and welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure you make your answer as clear as possible. For example: what do you mean by "upgrading the flutter pub"? Do you mean running `flutter pub upgrade`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that